# Resolving a promise in a dependent AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have a simple AngularJS app running in a Chrome Extension making use of the Storage API. Having an issue with the async nature of Storage; I've abstracted the storage away into a 'UserService' that sets and gets the data as a factory:

```
app.factory('UserService', 
  function($q, AppSettings) {
    var defaults = {
      api: {
        token: AppSettings.environments[1].api.token
      },
      email: ''
    };
    var service = {
      user: {},
      save: function() {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'user': angular.toJson(service.user)});        
      },
      restore: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        chrome.storage.sync.get('user', function(data) {
          if(!data) {
            chrome.storage.sync.set({'user': defaults});
            service.user = defaults;
          } else {
            service.user = angular.fromJson(data.user); 
          }
          deferred.resolve(service);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };

    // set the defaults
    service.restore().then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    });
});
```

The `console.log()` call above dumps out the data as expected. However, when I am including the UserService in other factories (I have an APIService that makes use of a user-specific API token), the UserService parameter is being flagged as 'undefined' in the code below:

```
app.factory('APIService', 
  function($resource, $http, UserService, AppSettings) {
    var token = UserService.user.api.token;
    ...
});
```

I am sure I am not fully grasping the Angular promise pattern in terms of consuming resolved promises throughout the app.

**Updated code:**

```
app.factory('UserService', 
  function($q, AppSettings) {
    var defaults = {
      api: {
        token: AppSettings.environments[1].api.token
      },
      email: ''
    };
    var service = {
      user: {},
      save: function() {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'user': angular.toJson(service.user)});        
      },
      restore: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        chrome.storage.sync.get('user', function(data) {
          if(!data) {
            chrome.storage.sync.set({'user': defaults});
            service.user = defaults;
          } else {
            service.user = angular.fromJson(data.user); 
          }
          deferred.resolve(service.user);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };

    // set the defaults
    service.restore().then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    });

    return service;
});
```

**Edit/Additional Info:**

Ok, getting close. Have refactored so that I am returning the object properly, but the issue now is that when the `APIService` gets created and tries to use the properties of the `UserService` object, they simply don't exist yet as they are only created after the async restore method is resolved. So it's not possible to access the `UserService.user.api.token` property, as it doesn't exist at that point, so the question is, how do I get that data in APIService when I need it if it is not available at that point? I'm trying to avoid having to put the entire contents of `APIService` into a callback that fires after a hypothetical new `UserService.get()` method that calls the callback on resolution of the promise. Any final guidance appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean `deferred.resolve(data);` instead of `deferred.resolve(service);`? You could just call the restore method. and chain through `UserService.restore().then((data)=>{ var token = data.api.token; })`

Comment: I'm including the resolved `data` value in the larger service object. If I call the restore method in the APIService, don't I then have to place all of the code of that factory in the `.then()` method? What if I have other promises to resolve?

Comment: The answer below is correct. You need to return the service: app.factory('UserService', 
  function($q, AppSettings) {   ....  return service;});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service is wrong. Please look at my fix:

```
app.factory('UserService', 
function($q, AppSettings) {
 var defaults = {
  api: {
    token: AppSettings.environments[1].api.token
  },
  email: ''
};
var service = {
  user: {},
  save: function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'user': angular.toJson(service.user)});        
  },
  restore: function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    chrome.storage.sync.get('user', function(data) {
      if(!data) {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'user': defaults});
        service.user = defaults;
      } else {
        service.user = angular.fromJson(data.user); 
      }
      deferred.resolve(service.user); // <--- return the user in here
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
};

// set the defaults
service.restore().then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  return data;
});

return service; // <--- return the service to be used injected when injected
});
```

[EDIT]
answer to your new question: Dont access user directly. create a new function in your service like getUser() that returns a promise. In that function return the user if it is already retreived otherwise return the restore() function:

```
var service = {
  user: null,
  getUser: function() {
       if (service.user)
       {
           var deferred = $q.defer();
           deferred.resolve(service.user);
           return deferred.promise;
       }
       else
           return service.restore();

  },
  save: function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'user': angular.toJson(service.user)});        
  },
  restore: function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    chrome.storage.sync.get('user', function(data) {
      if(!data) {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'user': defaults});
        service.user = defaults;
      } else {
        service.user = angular.fromJson(data.user); 
      }
      deferred.resolve(service.user); // <--- return the user in here
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, much appreciated. Made the changes you suggested and still not getting the resolved object in the APIService factory. Updating the question above with the full updated code.

Comment: One last additional bit of data - when I `console.log(UserService)`, I can see all of the properties... but when I try to specify the sub properties using dot notation (i.e. `console.log(UserService.user)`) I get just the `__proto__` property.

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning an object from your factory. So when you try to inject your `UserService` parameter, it gives undefined because you haven't returned anything from your UserService function.

If you return your `service` variable, I think you'll get the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Hmm, isn't the resolved `data` object that I am returning the service object itself? I have `deferred.resolve(service);` above - making the change you suggested didn't change the outcome.